# how to restrict horizontal strech of css flex

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am having a `div` with 3 child `div`s. I am using CSS flex for dynamically set the height of `div`. With 3 divs it's working fine.

But there may be a scenario where I will be having 2 child `div`s. Here child `div`s are stretching and taking full width of the page. How can I restrict this stretch using only CSS. Check its behaviour by removing `div` 3.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.flex-container .row {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="flex-item">DIV 1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">DIV 2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">DIV 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2 child `div`s streching like this

[image: 2 divs stretching taking entire width]

Comment: How should it look like when there is only 2 div's?

Comment: I also updated my answer with a second option

Comment: Can you please accept LGson's answer if it solved your problem or leave a comment if you need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flex-basis` might be an option

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container .row {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to set `flex-grow` to a number smaller than `1`

So i.e. achieve the same result as with `flex-basis`, you need to set `flex-shrink` to `0` and add an extra element inside the flex items to handle the margin's.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container .row {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 0.333 0;
} 
.flex-item div {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div>2</div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div>3</div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div>2</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```